# OpenLayers 3 - only call code on geolocation in IE11 if user allows it

Tags: openlayers, geolocation

I have a geolocation control in OpenLayers 3. The problem is that when clicked in IE11, the user is prompted for permission to geolocate. I want to pan to the geolocation position *if and after* that permission is granted. I think what happens with my code now is that it tries to pan before permission has been granted:

```
geolocation.setTracking(true);
map.getView().setCenter(geolocation.getPosition());
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
if(geolocation.position_ != null){
    map.getView().setCenter(geolocation.getPosition());
}
```

or:

```
if(geolocation.getPosition != 'undefined)
```